# Access Dynaset and Snapshot

Tags: ms-access, snapshot

I opened an old project of Access. I have some problems with these objects that are no longer used.
I'm following this guide: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/129883/en

The part of the code in question is this:

```
Private Sub AGG_Dati()

Dim Dyna As Dynaset
Dim DB As Database

Set DB = CurrentDb()
Set Dyna = DB.CreateDynaset("SELECT DISTINCTROW TOrdiniCartone.* FROM TOrdiniCartone WHERE ((TOrdiniCartone.[Tipo Ordine] = ""S""));")

If Dyna.RecordCount > 0 Then Dyna.MoveLast
n = Dyna.RecordCount
If n > 0 Then
    Dyna.MoveFirst
    If " " & Forms![SOrdiniArticoli].[_CArt] <> " " & Dyna.[Codice Articolo] Then
       Forms![SOrdiniArticoli].[_CArt] = Dyna.[Codice Articolo]
       Forms![SOrdiniArticoli].[_CForn] = ""
       MsgBox "Selezionare un Fornitore!"
       Stato = 1
    Else....
```

Following the guide, I changed to:

```
Private Sub AGG_Dati()

Dim Dyna As Recordset
Dim DB As Database

Set DB = CurrentDb()
Set Dyna = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCTROW TOrdiniCartone.* FROM TOrdiniCartone WHERE ((TOrdiniCartone.[Tipo Ordine] = ""S""));", dbOpenDynaset)
```

It gives me error here: Dyna.[Codice Articolo]

[Codice Articolo] is a field in the table TOrdiniCartone

Does anyone know these things?

Comment: What version of Access are you using now?

Comment: Now I'm using Access 2010, but the same mistakes I've also opening the database with Access 97. The problem is that at the time the programmer has used the syntax that was used for Access 1.0 .... However, with your help it works now.

Comment: Great, if my solution worked make sure to mark it as as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dyna should be defined as a dao.recordset:

```
Dim Dyna As DAO.Recordset
```

Fields can be referenced

```
Dyna.Fields("Field Name")
```

or

```
Dyna.Fields(<index>)
```

where index starts at 0 for the first column.

You can also do

```
Dyna![FieldName]
```